# Play videos with libwebkit in Ubuntu 11.10 server

Tags: video, codecs, webkit

I'm using libwebkit (with python-webkit) to render a page that plays a video. This application works fine in a Ubuntu 11.04 Desktop, Nvidia card and lots of libraries and software installed, but in a fresh Ubuntu 11.10 Server with intel 82945G/GZ card the video does not play.

I guess either some codec package is missing or it's a driver problem. What could be missing for this to play?

I'm trying with this video: http://video.eustasy.co.uk/480/

EDIT: doesn't look like a driver problem. With chromium I can play the video, but with libwebkit + python-webkit the video just shows the first frame and doesn't play. Any hints on what package could be missing?

SOLVED: apparently it had to do with lack of audio. While chrome would play the video with no sound, libwebkit wouldn't start video. Adding user to audio and video groups solved the problem.

Comment: You can add this edit as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

OP has resolved the problem and posted answer as an update to the question;

> SOLVED: apparently it had to do with lack of audio. While chrome would
>   play the video with no sound, libwebkit wouldn't start video. Adding
>   user to audio and video groups solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that Chrome has a better integration with X, if you had dealt with some missing codecs your browser should not even show the first frame.

If you check the library used by Chrome with

```
ldd /opt/google/chrome/chrome
```

you can easily find out that Chrome uses a good amount of library related to X where Firefox simply don't do the same.

```
ldd /opt/google/chrome/chrome | grep X
```

You can check the libraries used by firefox with

```
ldd /usr/lib/firefox-*/firefox
```

I think that this can be a problem related with the X buffer used by the codec that play your video.